# CSS descendants and other selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

With the following HTML, does my CSS display as I have stipulated below?

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
   <ul>
<li>3</li>
   </ul>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul + li   /* 1 and 3 */
ul > li   /* 1, 2 and 3 */
ul ~ li   /* 1, 2, 3 and 4 */
```

Equally important, where did I go wrong?

Comment: This first issue I see is that `ul` should only have `li`s as children. You can put a `ul` inside an `li`, but it shouldn't be a direct child of a `ul`. Second, `+` and `~` are both sibling selectors, so `ul + li` or `ul ~ li` should never match anything. But in your provided code both would only match the `li` with content 4. `>` is a direct child selector, so it would match all of your `li`s.

Comment: Check this out for a quick reference: https://techbrij.com/css-selector-adjacent-child-sibling

Comment: Use first-child, last-child, and nth-child() selectors for this instead. Your approach looks too specific.

Comment: shadymoses: Thanks for your link ... in spite of the link's excellence, I am having difficulty in understanding your 1st paragraph. For example, the 2nd ul is the 1st child of li(2), but  I think you said it was a direct child of the 1st ul. Another example ... li(1) is the 1st sibling of ul(1), yet you stated + and ~ should not match anything? Forgive my slowness, but I am really having trouble.

Comment: @JohnLove shadymoses is right; the second `ul` is a child of the first `ul`, which is incorrect. You should fix it so that the second `ul` is inside an `li`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a lot going on here so I'm going to try to break it down for you one by one. This will be long, but bear with me.

Let's make the indentation a little more consistent so we can see what's going on with the HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <ul>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

When you open the first `ul`, and start adding `li`s to it, those `li` elements are *children* of the first `ul`. They appear *inside* it, or more precisely, between its start tag `<ul>` and its end tag `</ul>`.

By the time you open the second `ul`, you've already closed the second `li` with its own end tag. The second `ul` is not a child of that `li` because it appears *after* its end tag `</li>`. So the second `ul` — the inner one if you will — is a *sibling* of the second `li`, and therefore a child of the first (outer) `ul`. The fourth `li`, similarly, is a sibling of the second `ul`, and also a child of the first `ul`.

The third `li` is a child of the second (inner) `ul`. It is neither a child nor a sibling of any of the other elements. It is a *grand*child of the first (outer) `ul`, but it doesn't matter for the sake of answering your question.

If the markup appears visually similar to a family tree, it should make sense to you. In a family tree, children appear under a parent. (Only, in a family tree, there are typically two parents; in HTML, every child has only one parent.) Children that are siblings of one another appear side by side, connected to the same parent. This markup is structured similarly, except the children are listed top to bottom instead of left to right. But they're still "side by side", logically speaking.

Recall what the following selectors do:

- `ul + li` matches a `li` that's a sibling appearing immediately after a `ul`.
- `ul > li` matches a `li` that's a child of a `ul`.
- `ul ~ li` matches a `li` that comes after a `ul` as a sibling, but unlike with `+` it doesn't have to appear immediately after, as long as they're between the same set of opening and closing tags (this is called "having the same parent element"). Any `ul + li` is automatically also a `ul ~ li`.

Here's the markup again with some annotations:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>   <!-- ul > li -->
  <li>2</li>   <!-- ul > li -->
  <ul>
    <li>3</li> <!-- ul > li -->
  </ul>
  <li>4</li>   <!-- ul > li, ul + li, ul ~ li -->
</ul>
```

Indeed, *none* of the first three `li` elements are siblings of any `ul`. Only the very last one is, and it matches both sibling selectors.

So how do you make the inner `ul` a child of the second `li`? You do this by moving the `</li>` so that it appears after the `</ul>` like so:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>     <!-- ul > li -->
  <li>2          <!-- ul > li -->
    <ul>
      <li>3</li> <!-- ul > li -->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>4</li>     <!-- ul > li, ul + li, ul ~ li -->
</ul>
```

Critically, the inner `ul` will now match a different selector: `li > ul`. Additionally, your markup will now validate, as you are never allowed to have a `ul` as a child of another `ul` in the first place.

Finally, some of your stipulations require more complex selectors as they match pretty specifically. I'll walk you through each one:

1. To match 1 and 3, use `ul > li:first-child`. This is because 1 and 3 are the first children of their respective parent `ul`s. You can usually tell if an element is the first child of another because its start tag is the first thing that appears after the parent's start tag, ignoring any text or whitespace.
2. To match 1, 2 and 3, use `ul > li:first-child, ul > li:nth-child(2)`. The additional `:nth-child(2)` targets item 2 specifically.
3. To match 1, 2, 3 and 4, using `ul > li` is enough, since you're just matching them all. You can probably get away with just `li` if you only have `ul` in your markup, but this is unlikely to be the case so I'm erring on the side of being more specific than necessary, rather than not being specific enough.

It's a lot to take in, so let me know if any of this is confusing or overwhelming and I'll try to address your concerns.

Comment: Quite the contrary. Your response says the “what” AND the “why”. I was not looking for “It’s wrong, period!”. I was seeking “It’s wrong for these reasons AND here’s the correct way”. You are an excellent teacher and THANK YOU.

Comment: @John Love: Thank you, that's quite an honor :)

Comment: Just one question for now. WRT your redo of my original markup, li-4 is one of several siblings of the 1st ul, so ul>li works. So does ul~li. But not ??? ul+li because li-4 does not ??? immediately follow its parent = the 1st ul.

Comment: It's one of several *children*, not siblings, of the 1st ul. But you're right, I made a mistake; because the 2nd ul is in li-3, the 2nd ul is no longer a sibling of any of the li items, because it's now a child of one of them. So li+li ends up matching all including li-4. I'll revise my answer.